# Positioning 2 QDialog forms relative to one each other

Tags: qt

I have created 2 QDialogs forms, D1 and D2. How is it possible to make D1 and D2 have a constant distance from each other (If I move D1, D2 also moves and vise versa)?

Comment: Have you tried [`QLayout`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlayout.html) or it's derived classes ?

Comment: According to the documentation, QLayout works for positioning widgets within a QDialog or QForm. In my case, I have two independent QDialogs so QLayout will not do.

Comment: Are these top-level dialogs?  That is, are they parented by the desktop window rather than an application window/widget?

Comment: Yes, both are top level windows.

Comment: Could you show what you've tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it'll end up being a bit tedious but one thing you might try is to have both dialogs parented by a *minimalist* container using a window mask.  So something like...

```
class minimalist_container: public QWidget {
  using super = QWidget;
public:
  explicit minimalist_container (QWidget *parent = nullptr)
    : super(parent)
    {}
protected:
  virtual void resizeEvent (QResizeEvent *event) override
    {

      /*
       * Start with an empty mask.
       */
      QRegion mask;

      /*
       * Now loop though the children and add a region to
       * the mask for each child based on its geometry.
       */
      for (const auto *obj: children()) {
        if (const auto *child = dynamic_cast<const QWidget *>(obj)) {
          mask += child->geometry();
        }
      }
      setMask(mask);
      super::resizeEvent(event);
    }
};
```

Then you can add a layout and children to this in the usual way but the parent itself should be essentially invisible...

```
minimalist_container minimalist_container;
auto *minimalist_container_layout = new QHBoxLayout;
minimalist_container_layout->addWidget(new QColorDialog);
minimalist_container_layout->addStretch(1);
minimalist_container_layout->addWidget(new QFontDialog);
minimalist_container.setLayout(minimalist_container_layout);
minimalist_container.show();
```

The code above *links* all children within the masked parent widget so that they appear visually distinct but move together when the parent is moved.

There are a few niggles however.  The title bar of the parent is, by default, the only one visible whereas what I think you really want is for the parent title bar to be the only one that *isn't* visible.  It can certainly be hidden by setting the window flags and/or configuring your window manager but you'll probably then have to write code to handle the usual move, resize functions etc.

So, as I say... tedious, but it could certainly work.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'll try this out as soon as I can.

Answer (score 0):

You can install an event filter to monitor the moving/resizing of the source window and propagate changes to the target window. On OS X, you also need to monitor the non-client area button press, since the window move events are not sent while the window is moving, but only after it has stopped for a short time.

I leave the propagation in opposite direction as an exercise to the reader :)

```
// https://github.com/KubaO/stackoverflown/tree/master/questions/win-move-track-42019943
#include <QtWidgets>

class WindowOffset : public QObject {
   Q_OBJECT
   QPoint m_offset, m_ref;
   QPointer<QWidget> m_src, m_dst;
   void adjust(QEvent * event, const QPoint & delta = QPoint{}) {
      qDebug() << "ADJUST" << delta << event;
      m_dst->move(m_src->geometry().topRight() + m_offset + delta);
   }
protected:
   bool eventFilter(QObject *watched, QEvent *event) override {
#ifdef Q_OS_OSX
      if (watched == m_src.data()) {
         if (event->type() == QEvent::NonClientAreaMouseButtonPress) {
            m_ref = QCursor::pos();
            qDebug() << "ACQ" << m_ref << event;
         }
         else if (event->type() == QEvent::NonClientAreaMouseMove &&
                  static_cast<QMouseEvent*>(event)->buttons() == Qt::LeftButton) {
            auto delta = QCursor::pos() - m_ref;
            adjust(event, delta);
         }
      }
#endif
      if ((watched == m_src.data() &&
                (event->type() == QEvent::Move || event->type() == QEvent::Resize)) ||
               (watched == m_dst.data() && event->type() == QEvent::Show)) {
         if (event->type() == QEvent::Move)
            m_ref = QCursor::pos();
         adjust(event);
      }
      return false;
   }
public:
   WindowOffset(const QPoint & offset, QObject * parent = nullptr) :
      QObject{parent},
      m_offset{offset}
   {}
   WindowOffset(QWidget * src, QWidget * dst, const QPoint & offset, QObject * parent = nullptr) :
      WindowOffset{offset, parent}
   {
      src->installEventFilter(this);
      dst->installEventFilter(this);
      m_src = src;
      m_dst = dst;
   }
};

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
   QApplication app{argc, argv};
   QLabel d1{"Source"}, d2{"Target"};
   WindowOffset offset{&d1, &d2, {200, 50}};
   for (auto d : {&d1, &d2}) {
      d->setMinimumSize(300,100);
      d->show();
   }
   return app.exec();
}

#include "main.moc"
```

Comment: It seems there is no simple way to do this. I'll try this out.